# DELPHI and WANT or NANT

Tags: delphi, cruisecontrol.net, nant

We use [cruise control .net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)  to do our Continuous Integration in our Delphi 2006 application. We use a setup similar to the one described [here](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/VideoSettingUpAContinuousIntegrationEnvironment.aspx).

**QUESTION:**

1)  What is the best scripting tool/language to use implement the build script?

2)  Are there any advantages of using [WANT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/want/) over using [NANT](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)?

(NOTE: D2006 is not compatible with MSBuild)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I never used WANT, but NANT works fine with any Delphi version. I presume NANT is also better supported and has more features you can use since it is used more widely then WANT.

BTW: You can still use MSBuild and call dcc32 if you want. In that way it is the same as NANT. If you move to Delphi 2007 MSBuild has a bigger advantage over NANT since the Delphi projects are in the MSBuild format. But even then you can still use NANT as a buildscript. It will just call out to MSBuild to do the separate builds.

Another build tool that is worth checking out is [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/). It is very complete and knows Delphi. It should, since it is build using Delphi. They also offer a CruiseControl like Continuous Integration solution. The drawback is that FinalBuilder is not free.

Answer (score 1):

Only couple of days back I managed to implement a complex NANT scripts to compile our projects (which uses d7-2009 compilers, VC++ 2005 and subversion). It was very easy to setup and work when used with [NantGui](http://nantgui.berlios.de/) .Unlike MSBuild you dont have to have certain version of .NET installed in your system.

For compiling the projects using dcc32, have a look at the [delphi3000](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4585.asp?SK=) article

Answer (score 0):

I used XSL to generate the Cruisecontrol project file automatically. We had a large project with many Delphi applications which already used a common Ant script. So generating the CC project file using a script was a natural solution.

Another Continuous Integration solution which works with Ant (and many others) is TeamCity. It is free up to a certain number of build agents / projects. The user interface is awesome.

I successfully use Ant for many years now for all kinds of Delphi projects, from small component libraries to multi-project multi-tier applications.