# Output binary files linked my version-control server without a build system?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am trying to setup a internal Mercurial HgWeb server on a Windows 2003 server. The Hgweb part is working. I could just share a folder to put released binary files for each projects. But I am wandering could I still somehow link the version control system with binary build output. So when there is a commit, the build output will automated get update as well for a release?

I know I could have a build system on the server end. But for Delphi, C#, ASP.NET projects and with a few third-party libraries, it seems much more work.

Right now, I am thinking about for each project I will have two repository, one for development (not output binary), the other for release which will including everything including the build result binaries (or only build result including dependency will be a better idea?). But I don't know yet how to make those two synchronize automatically without manually commit twice.

Maybe simply a hook on Dev repository fires every time commit to Master branch which will make another commit to the Release branch?

Comment: Do you really need to host those in a Mercurial repository? Can't you make regular downloads available for them through a normal website instead?

Comment: @Lasse V. It is not necessary, but I am thinking one place is better than two place/website? The more important thing for me is to be able get new version of binary published for a new release. Not a version-control related question, probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a build system like [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) to build your binaries after pushes happen to a remote repository that CC.NET is watching.  The binaries built can then just be copied to a standard Web server to be served up for download.  CC.NET is not complicated to configure and [supports Mercurial out-of-the-box](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Mercurial+Source+Control+Block).  Using a system like this, you can get the extras like build stats, [run unit tests](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/NUnit+Task) before pushing a build to be downloaded, and lots more.

Comment: Sounds good, especially if it is easy to config. But we are not a .Net only shop, how about Delphi?

Comment: You'll want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510476/delphi-and-want-or-nant) and review some of the links provided.  CCNET supports using both MSBuild and NAnt for your build system and both can build Delphi projects.  Configuring CCNET build projects, you'd just have multiple build steps that build both your .NET projects and Delphi projects if they need to be done together, or you can set up separate build projects.

Comment: reading along CCNET and NAnt make me realize that Delphi can be build pretty much like C\C++ using Ant-like script. Thank for the link.

Comment: From your comments, it seems @Sumos's answer has guided you to the direction you want to go, why not voting it up then?